# TrackMouseEvent not working

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Basically, I call `TrackMouseEvent` in my `WM_CREATE` then I also called it again after a `WM_MOUSELEAVE` event, but this freezes up my program.

Where should I be sticking it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to call `TrackMouseEvent` when the mouse enters your control, and not when it leaves your control.

You can call `TrackMouseEvent` on the `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message.  You don't need to call `TrackMouseEvent` every time `WM_MOUSEMOVE` is fired, just once up until you get another `WM_MOUSELEAVE`.  After you get a `WM_MOUSELEAVE` you can set some flag so the next call to `WM_MOUSEMOVE` will know to call `TrackMouseEvent` again.

Basically you can emulate a fictional `WM_MOUSEENTER` by using `WM_MOUSEMOVE` and also having that flag set.