# How to handle mouse hover event for specific control in Microsoft visual C++ ( MFC )?

Tags: c++, mfc, hover, mouseevent

In my application I need to handle mouse hover event to change the background of a button. Using the MFC class wizard, I couldn't find a mouse hover entry in the list of events for that item. I tried using `PreTranslateMessage`, but it doesn't work. How can I handle that event?

Answer (score 5):

Mouse hover events aren't generated by default. You have to request them by calling [TrackMouseEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646265.aspx) with a properly populated [TRACKMOUSEEVENT structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645604.aspx):

```
TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme = { 0 };
tme.cbSize = sizeof( tme );
tme.dwFlags = TME_HOVER;
tme.hwndTrack = myButton;
tme.dwHoverTime = myHoverTime;  // HOVER_DEFAULT, or the hover timeout in milliseconds.
::TrackMouseEvent( &tme );
```

The system will then generate [WM_MOUSEHOVER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645613.aspx) messages if the mouse hovers over *myButton* for *myHoverTime* milliseconds.

Since the `WM_MOUSEHOVER` message is posted to the window that requested mouse hover messages, you will have to derive a custom button control, with appropriate entries in its message map. In particular, you will have to use the `ON_WM_MOUSEHOVER()` macro and implement [afx_msg void OnMouseHover(UINT, CPoint)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398065.aspx) (see [WM_ Message Handlers: L - M](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a37549wh.aspx) for reference).

Comment: Usage of TrackMouseEvent() - start tracking on WM_MOUSEMOVE, and stop on mouse leave (WM_MOUSELEAVE). For receiving mouse move you won't be required to call TrackMouseEvent(). For mouse leave you will be. specify TME_LEAVE when starting tracking (this will ensure that you will get WM_MOUSELEAVE event), and then in mouse leave handler use TME_CANCEL to stop tracking. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2886595/981766