# How to get button text by hovering the mouse from a 3rd party program?

Tags: c++, winapi

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    POINT p;
    char wndName[60];
    while (true)
    {
        GetCursorPos(&p);
        HWND hWnd = WindowFromPoint(p);

        GetWindowText(hWnd, wndName, 59);
        std::cout << p.x << " " << p.y << std::endl;
        std::cout << wndName << " " << std::endl;
        ScreenToClient(hWnd, &p);
        HWND hWndChild = ChildWindowFromPoint(hWnd, p);
        GetWindowText(hWndChild, wndName, 59);
        std::cout << p.x << " " << p.y << std::endl;
        std::cout << wndName << " " << std::endl;
        Sleep(100);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Printing the name from the parent window works fine, but I can't make it to work for the child window. 
The GetWindowText() of the child handle just prints the same as the parent handle.

I want my program to print button text, text in edit fields, etc. just by hovering the mouse cursor.

EDIT: Any tips to help me solve this problem?

Comment: You could try referring to this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33191480/9850717). Probably lacking an event handler to handle your mouse events

Comment: You have no error checking code at all. First step is to add that and so debug your program.

Comment: I forgot to add, I am hovering from a 3rd party program.

Comment: You still have no error checking code. Why not? And then there's the documentation which says *However, GetWindowText cannot retrieve the text of a control in another application.* Did you read this?

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing any error handling. Most importantly, the second `GetWindowText()` fails and does not update your `wndName` buffer, which is why you see the parent text get printed a second time.

You *cannot* use `GetWindowText()` to get the text of a child window in another process. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtexta) even says so:

> If the specified window is a control, the text of the control is copied. **`GetWindowText` cannot retrieve the text of a control in another application.**
>   ...
>   To retrieve the text of a control in another process, send a [`WM_GETTEXT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632627.aspx) message directly instead of calling `GetWindowText()`.

Try this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

const int MAX_WND_TEXT = 60;

int main()
{
    POINT p;
    char wndName[MAX_WND_TEXT];

    while (true)
    {
        GetCursorPos(&p);
        HWND hWnd = WindowFromPoint(p);
        if (hWnd)
        {
            if (!GetWindowTextA(hWnd, wndName, MAX_WND_TEXT))
                wndName[0] = '\0';

            std::cout << p.x << " " << p.y << std::endl;
            std::cout << "'" << wndName << "'" << std::endl;

            ScreenToClient(hWnd, &p);
            HWND hWndChild = ChildWindowFromPoint(hWnd, p);
            if (hWndChild)
            {
                if (!SendMessageA(hWndChild, WM_GETTEXT, MAX_WND_TEXT, (LPARAM)wndName))
                    wndName[0] = '\0';

                std::cout << p.x << " " << p.y << std::endl;
                std::cout << "'" << wndName << "'" << std::endl;
            }
        }

        Sleep(100);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**: However, per the following post on Raymond Chen's blog:

[WindowFromPoint, ChildWindowFromPoint, RealChildWindowFromPoint, when will it all end?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101230-00/?p=11873)

> Suppose you have a top-level window P and a child window C. And suppose you ask one of the above functions, "What window is beneath this point?" when the point is squarely over window C. **The WindowFromPoint function looks for the most heavily nested window that contains the point, which is window C**. On the other hand ChildWindowFromPoint function looks for the least nested window that contains the point, which is window P, assuming you passed GetDesktopWindow as the starting point.

So, `WindowFromPoint()` will return the deepest child at the specified screen coordinate, so there will not be any further child window for `ChildWindowFromPoint()` to find when the specified parent window is gotten from `WindowFromPoint()`.

And per the [`ChildWindowFromPoint()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-childwindowfrompoint) documentation:

> If the point is within the parent window but not within any child window, **the return value is a handle to the parent window**.

So, the above code will not have the result you are looking for.  You would need something more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

const int MAX_WND_TEXT = 60;

int main()
{
    POINT p;
    char wndName[MAX_WND_TEXT];

    while (true)
    {
        GetCursorPos(&p);
        HWND hWnd = ChildWindowFromPoint(GetDesktopWindow(), p);
        if (hWnd)
        {
            if (!GetWindowTextA(hWnd, wndName, MAX_WND_TEXT))
                wndName[0] = '\0';

            std::cout << p.x << " " << p.y << std::endl;
            std::cout << "'" << wndName << "'" << std::endl;

            ScreenToClient(hWnd, &p);
            HWND hWndChild = ChildWindowFromPoint(hWnd, p);
            if ((hWndChild) && (hWndChild != hWnd))
            {
                if (!SendMessageA(hWndChild, WM_GETTEXT, MAX_WND_TEXT, (LPARAM)wndName))
                    wndName[0] = '\0';

                std::cout << p.x << " " << p.y << std::endl;
                std::cout << "'" << wndName << "'" << std::endl;
            }
        }

        Sleep(100);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But, this code exhibits problems with **z-ordering**, finding windows that are behind other windows instead of on top of them.  You might need something more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

const int MAX_WND_TEXT = 60;

int main()
{
    POINT p;
    char wndName[MAX_WND_TEXT];

    while (true)
    {
        GetCursorPos(&p);

        HWND hWnd = WindowFromPoint(p);
        if (hWnd)
        {
            HWND hWndRoot = GetAncestor(hWnd, GA_ROOTOWNER); // or GetAncestor(GA_ROOT), or GetAncestor(GA_PARENT), or GetParent(), as needed...
            HWND hWndChild = NULL;

            if ((hWndRoot) && (hWndRoot != hWnd))
            {
                hWndChild = hWnd;
                hWnd = hWndRoot;
            }

            if (!GetWindowTextA(hWnd, wndName, MAX_WND_TEXT))
                wndName[0] = '\0';

            std::cout << p.x << " " << p.y << std::endl;
            std::cout << "'" << wndName << "'" << std::endl;

            if (hWndChild)
            {
                ScreenToClient(hWndChild, &p);

                if (!SendMessageA(hWndChild, WM_GETTEXT, MAX_WND_TEXT, (LPARAM)wndName))
                    wndName[0] = '\0';

                std::cout << p.x << " " << p.y << std::endl;
                std::cout << "'" << wndName << "'" << std::endl;
            }
        }

        Sleep(100);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It is still not perfect, but it is better than the previous code.

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried checking the HWND values and it shows that the parent and child are equal. I'm still a beginner in winapi though.

Comment: Are there other ways to get it though?

Comment: It works on other cases like some buttons on the Control Panel, but I want to get text from buttons from other programs. I'm creating a Qt program and wanted to get the text of a button as a test. Btw, great effort.

Comment: I am not familiar with Qt's internals. You are assuming Qt uses standard windowed controls for its buttons and not custom-drawn graphical controls. This code fails for non-windowed controls since they don't exist as separate entities to the OS.

Comment: oh well, thanks maybe I should try using OCR instead.

Comment: Or perhaps UI Automation.  Its really hard to tell you what to use without knowing what you are trying to accomplish in the first place.

Answer (score -2):

Use [ChildWindowFromPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-childwindowfrompoint) after getting the top level window handle.

Comment: Notice that the code in the question includes a call to `ChildWindowFromPoint`.

Comment: That's what I am doing, but it only returns the text of the parent handle. For example, when I hover at visual studio program it reads the title, but when I hover at the buttons it just return the program title.

Comment: What buttons?  the toolbar? These are not HWNDs.